# a Variable rehostate servo Motor to discharge a Tesla S model battery

Tags: batteries, motor, servo, variable

Anyone could help me to find a Variable rehostate with servo Motor to modify load on a high power system. I am trying to discharge a Tesla S model battery.

Comment: Do you mean 'rheostat'? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: what is a `variable rheostat servo motor`?  ... a rheostat is a variable resistor, so `variable rheostat` is redundant .... how does the rheostat relate to the servo motor?

Comment: We don't help people find things here. We answer questions about electrical engineering design and theory. I am voting to close the question. A rheostat with a power rating comparable to the power rating of the motor in a Tesla model S is going to be pretty difficult to construct. One that I have heard about are were constructed using tanks of saltwater with electrodes in them raised in lowered using some kind of hoist mechanism. Stainless steel might be a good electrode material.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_rheostat

Comment: @CharlesCowie Stainless as an electrode can be problematic : the electrolyte tends to contain chromates afterwards. which you don't want to just dump anywhere. (Erin Brockovich and all that)